# geojson layer from geoserver not showing (openlayer)

Tags: openlayers, geojson, geoserver

i have this script running:

```
var map;

  var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  renderer: ol.RendererHint.CANVAS,
  view: new ol.View2D({
    center: ol.proj.transform([16.37, 48.21], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 11
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuestOpenAerial()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'http://ginyu.at:8080/geoserver/wienbike/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=wienbike%3Ainput2&maxfeatures=50&outputformat=json',
        parser: new ol.parser.GeoJSON()
      })
    })
  ]
});
```

why is the layer not showing. im getting sometimes a "not enough permgen space" error from geoserver? is that related to that problem? or do i need to make any adjustements to geoserver to publish maps? if you enter just the url in the browser you get the geojson code. many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just to point that your geojson file has no problems, but it's has two points, one near Budapest and the other one close to Yemen (I used http://geojsonlint.com/ for that)

[image]

would that be the problem?

Comment: thx. that shouldnt be the problem. i just deleted the records from the database. i think its somewthing with geoserver..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Openlayers you could try using the Openlayers GeoRSS layer instead of a vector layer. There are a number of things that can need configuring inside of openlayers when using vector layers to get data.

Try something like:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.GeoRSS( 'GeoRSS Layer', 'http://ginyu.at:8080/geoserver/wienbike/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=wienbike%3Ainput2&maxfeatures=50&outputformat=json');
```

If going to the link shows the GeooRSS code then it is very ubnlikely that the problem is with geoserver and is instead with how openlayers is trying to deal with the data.

If you really want to use a vector then try using these options to let Openlayers know how to handle the data. What is particularly important is the strategy as this lets Openlayers know when to go and get the data ect and the format as it lets it know what format the data is in.

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoRSS Layer", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "http://ginyu.at:8080/geoserver/wienbike/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=wienbike%3Ainput2&maxfeatures=50&outputformat=jsonl",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoRSS()
    })
});
```

One final thing to check is that your map and your data use the same projection. The line:

```
ol.proj.transform([16.37, 48.21], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
```

Suggests that you are expecting your map to be in EPSG:3857. I can't see that you have set the map to that projection anywhere though. As you are using the MapQuestOpenAriel layer I it is liekly that that is the correct projection. That may not be a problem if all your data is in the same project. You will want to make sure that your georss data is in that projection though. Looking at the data coming through your GeoRSS feed it appears to be in EPSG: 4326. This means that it will not project correctly over you map. This means your will need to reproject the co-ordinates of your GeoRSS data. We can do this by specifying the projection in the Openlayers GeoRSS layer:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.GeoRSS( 'GeoRSS Layer', 
                              'http://ginyu.at:8080/geoserver/wienbike/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=wienbike%3Ainput2&maxfeatures=50&outputformat=json',
                               {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")}
);
```

I have not been able to find any documentation on a 'parser" variable for Openlayers. This could mean that you are using a different library or an older one. If that is the case what I have said above may be of no help.